# Java REST Client: print get request (json)?

Tags: java, rest, get, client, jira

I'm trying to print the returned value of a GET request in Java to the Jira REST API but it doesn't seem to work for me. The authentication works fine but somehow the code doesn't print anything.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String user = "myusername";
    String password = "mypassword";

    Client client = ClientBuilder
            .newClient()
            .register(new Authenticator(user,password));

     String response = client
            .target("https://justanotherlink.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/test")
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(String.class);

    System.out.print(response);

}
```

It should have returned and printed the some kind of json formated String but it doesn't. It prints nothing at all. I tried it with:

```
     Response response = client 
              ...
             .get(Response.class)
```

it printed:

```
 InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=https://justanotherlink.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/test, status=200, reason=200}}
```

regarding that status/reason is 200 (OK) my request went through. Any idea why printing as String doesn't work here? Postman delivers the expected Json.

EDIT:
It's working as intended now. The only real thing I changed was to put the response into a String variable before printing it... I assume because of the length of the String (about 7000 symbols) the Sysout command couldn't handle it or something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
Response response = client 
              ...
             .get(Response.class)
```

is correct. To retrieve the content, you need to

```
String content = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.print(content);
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but the programm somehow still terminates without printing any String.

Comment: Did you add "System.out.print(content);" ?

Comment: Yes I did ^^ But it seems to be the same result as in my first code. And that is no result :o

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that sometimes (very rarely) it does print the expected result. That only happend 2 times in about 300 tries. I dont know why but even if i use the same code it sometimes works and sometimes doesnt. Also to correct myself: It doesnt print "nothing" it prints a bunch of empty spaces. I assume it replaced the symbols it should have printed with empty spaces. Still having no idea why that happens tho...